# Restrict UIPageViewController (with TransitionStyleScroll) pan gesture to a certain area

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uigesturerecognizer, uipageviewcontroller

In my app I have a RootPageViewController which contains the UIPageViewController and one or more DetailPageViewController with a UITableView as a childview.

```
                          DetailPageViewController
                        / 
RootPageViewController  - DetailPageViewController
                        \
                          DetailPageViewController
```

On top of every DetailPageViewController is a little space where it should be possible to swipe and get to the next DetailPageViewController.

```
 ------------------- 
|                   |
|                   |  -> UIPageViewController should respond to pan's
|                   |
|-------------------|   --------------------------------------------
|  CellContent      |  
|-------------------|
|  CellContent      |
|-------------------|  -> UIPageViewController should disable UIPageViewController pan's
|  CellContent      |
|-------------------|
|  ...              |
```

In the iOS 7 weather app is a scrollview with the whole weak forecast who somehow overwrites or disables the the pan of the UIPageViewController.

How can I recreate such behavior ?

Sorry for the missing screenshots

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I do it by subclassing the UIPageViewController, finding its UIScrollView (iterate self.subviews), and adding a new UIPanGestureRecognizer to that scrollView.

I set my subclassed UIPageViewController to be the delegate of that new UIPanGestureRegognizer. I then implement two delegate methods:

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer
{
  return NO;
}
```

and in

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizerShouldBegin:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
```

I decide if I want to "eat the event" (reply YES) or if I want the original UIPanGestureViewRecognizer of the UIScrollView to handle it (reply NO). So, the YES-reply means the UIPageViewController will not scroll to the next ViewController.

Comment: http://www.lukaszielinski.de/blog/posts/2014/03/26/restrict-panning-of-uipageviewcontroller-to-certain-area/
Much detailed answer here which says the same thing

Comment: Well, no need to add an additional panGestureRecognizer! You can have the same behavior with the supplied one and without having to do all this gestureRecognizershouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer: business... ;-)

Answer (score 1):

My solution in Swift:

```
let myview = UIView(frame: CGRect(x:0, y:0, width:320, height:320))
//dummy view that defines the area where the gesture works
self.view.addSubview(myview)

for x in self.pageViewController!.view.subviews 
{ if x is UIScrollView
  { myview.addGestureRecognizer(x.panGestureRecognizer) } 
}
```