# How to disable paging of UIPageViewController only for landscape orientation?

Tags: ios, swift, uipageviewcontroller, uiinterfaceorientation, device-orientation

I have a **scroll** transition style `UIPageViewController` that needs to disable paging only when device is in landscape orientation. But paging should be enabled in portrait orientation.

I have encountered similar questions here in SO but not my specific need. Some of them are:

[How do I Disable the swipe gesture of UIPageViewController?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22098493/how-do-i-disable-the-swipe-gesture-of-uipageviewcontroller)

[Disable Page scrolling in UIPageViewController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27171786/disable-page-scrolling-in-uipageviewcontroller)

[Disable/enable scrolling in UIPageViewController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15829197/disable-enable-scrolling-in-uipageviewcontroller/37876562)

[Restrict UIPageViewController (with TransitionStyleScroll) pan gesture to a certain area](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21461847/restrict-uipageviewcontroller-with-transitionstylescroll-pan-gesture-to-a-cert)

All of the above points to either completely disabling or restricting pan gesture to a certain area.

### Now if I take the approach of completely disabling:

- I will need to track device orientation change
- Disable when orientation is set to landscape
- Again enable when orientation is changed to portrait

### If I take the approach of restricting to a certain area:

- I will need to find that **certain** area
- That certain area (described in previous point) needs to be calculated
  differently for portrait & landscape orientation
- Certain area for portrait orientation needs to be the area of the
  whole `UIPageViewController` bounds
- Certain area for landscape orientation needs to be a very minimum area
  (whose frame could be `0`, `0`, `1`, `1`) where user won't be able to
  perform pan operation. This frame calculation needs to be very
  precise because my `UIPageViewController` takes the whole bounds of
  the main screen in landscape orientation.
- Then again may need to track device orientation change for different
  calculation of the **certain area**

---

There are some techniques where the authors suggest:

```
pvc.dataSource = nil // prevents paging

pvc.dataSource = `a valid dataSource object` // enables paging
```

So, manual enable + disable again. Track orientation change and enable/disable.

This isn't safe to use for my specific use case as there is a possibility of assigning data source multiple times.

---

There are other approaches which, I think, can't be modified to fit the use case.

Is there a shortcut way to achieve what I need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering to my own question as I've already achieved what I needed to.

Subclassing `UIPageViewController` is the easiest way. We have to find the underlying `UIScrollView` that is used by the page view controller to handle its pan gesture related work. We will add another `UIPanGestureRecognizer` to that internal scroll view. This pan gesture recognizer won't perform any action essentially but it will block the internal pan gesture recognizer to be recognized for landscape orientation only.

Sample implementation:

```
class CustomPageViewController: UIPageViewController, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        if let underlyingScrollView = view.subviews.compactMap({ $0 as? UIScrollView })
                                    .first {

            let pangestureRecognizer = UIPanGestureRecognizer()
            pangestureRecognizer.delegate = self
            underlyingScrollView.addGestureRecognizer(pangestureRecognizer)
            // at this point, the underlying scroll view will have two pan gesture
            // recognizer side by side. We have the control of our added pan gesture
            // recognizer through the delegate. We can conditionally recognize it or not
        }
    }

    func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, 
         shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWith otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) 
         -> Bool {
        // Returning true from here means, page view controller will behave as it is
        // Returning false means, paging will be blocked
        // As I needed to block paging only for landscape orientation, I'm just returning
        // if orientation is in portrait or not
        return UIApplication.shared.statusBarOrientation.isPortrait
    }

}
```